# Simple software to make short animation

Tags: video, animation

I'm looking for a simple software to create small video Ads. Like using a stick man to do something, any recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Flash](http://download.cnet.com/Adobe-Flash-Professional/3000-6676_4-10018718.html)

It makes doing simple animations pretty straight forward.